# Unable to Download Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: mac, macos, mac-appstore

I currently have Mac OS X Mavericks.  When I try to download Yosemite from the App Store the file begins to download and shows an estimated time.  After a few minutes the file stops downloading and the estimated time is now replaced by "calculating".  After calculating for a minute or so the App Store stops trying to download and shows an error has occurred.

I have deleted the file and started fresh several times and restarted my computer each time ending up with the same error each time.

All of my updates have been installed.

Please help!

Comment: Does your network have limits on the size/duration of downloads? Some so, especially public/hotel/school/work networks...

Comment: Good question.  No I have good network access with no size limits.

Comment: Are you on a WiFi network? If your computer's network silenty drops, then the download could be broken and the appStore downloader is unable to figure out how to pause/continue. Is it possible you try on a different wifi network and/or placing your computer as near to the wifi router, so to keep your wifi network as fast+stable as possible...

Comment: sometimes the apple server has some problems. try this link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-yosemite/id915041082?mt=12

Comment: Are you with BT? They seem to limit downloads to 4GB.